# Creating a web-services client in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, netbeans, client

I need to create a web services client in java/Eclipse to interface with a test management tool from my java testing code.

I successfully set up the client in NetBeans.  This was a fairly painless process using NetBeans' wizard.

However, Eclipse is our IDE of choice, so I need to get the code over to it.  I have found and followed steps to implement a web services client in Eclipse.  The process in Eclipse is a lot clunkier IMO, but I successfully generated the client.

However, Netbeans and Eclipse don't seem to agree on what the information in the wsdl file means.  NetBeans discovers/creates a larger collection of classes in its 'generated sources' folder than Eclipse does.

I must be missing something?

Looking for anyone who tried to create a ws client in both Netbeans and Eclipse, and is able to shed some light on why there are differences in the code created from the wsdl file, and how to work around it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just generate the client on Netbeans and use the generated code in Eclipse?

Comment: My thought exactly.  However, when I did that, part of the code I wrote in the Netbeans client didn't work in Eclipse because some classes were not available (not dicovered by Eclipse).  That's what I meant when I said that Netbeans discovers more in the wsdl file than Eclipse apparently.

Comment: I guess I could just copy everything over, but I was hoping to find out how Eclipse misses some of the classes.

Comment: Wizards are different and do not compare solely on the number of classes generated by a tool.  Compare functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a client using the wizard "Web Service Client" Eclipse, you are using a runtime for WS. I'm using Java EE developer version of Eclipse Helios (3.6) + JBoss Tools, With JBoss 6.0 server, and I have 4 different runtimes available.

1. Apache Axis
2. Apache Axis2
3. Apache CXF 2.x
4. JBossWS

Which runtime (framework) are you using under Netbeans?
Using JBossWS, I generated WS client classes from WSDL, and I'm using them in a maven Java EE 6 application, deployed to a JBoss 6.0, and it works perfectly, inside Eclipse and outside (deployed).